# Form does not display any input I type

Tags: reactjs

I have created the following form in my web app. The form and the other part of the page is displayed properly.

```
               <div className="col-12 col-md-9">
                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                        <FormGroup row>
                            <Label htmlFor="firstname" md={2}>First Name</Label>
                            <Col md={10}>
                                <Input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"
                                    placeholder="First Name"
                                    value={this.state.firstname}
                                    onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup row>
                            <Label htmlFor="lastname" md={2}>Last Name</Label>
                            <Col md={10}>
                                <Input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname"
                                    placeholder="Last Name"
                                    value={this.state.lastname}
                                    onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                            </Col>                        
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup row>
                        <Label htmlFor="telnum" md={2}>Contact Tel.</Label>
                            <Col md={10}>
                                <Input type="tel" id="telnum" name="telnum"
                                    placeholder="Tel. number"
                                    value={this.state.telnum}
                                    onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup row>
                            <Label htmlFor="email" md={2}>Email</Label>
                            <Col md={10}>
                                <Input type="email" id="email" name="email"
                                    placeholder="Email"
                                    value={this.state.email}
                                    onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup row>
                            <Col md={{size: 6, offset: 2}}>
                                <FormGroup check>
                                    <Label check>
                                        <Input type="checkbox"
                                            name="agree"
                                            checked={this.state.agree}
                                            onChange={this.handleInputChange} /> {' '}
                                        <strong>May we contact you?</strong>
                                    </Label>
                                </FormGroup>
                            </Col>
                            <Col md={{size: 3, offset: 1}}>
                                <Input type="select" name="contactType"
                                        value={this.state.contactType}
                                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}>
                                    <option>Tel.</option>
                                    <option>Email</option>
                                </Input>
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup row>
                            <Label htmlFor="message" md={2}>Your Feedback</Label>
                            <Col md={10}>
                                <Input type="textarea" id="message" name="message"
                                    rows="12"
                                    value={this.state.message}
                                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}></Input>
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup row>
                            <Col md={{size: 10, offset: 2}}>
                                <Button type="submit" color="primary">
                                    Send Feedback
                                </Button>
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Form>
                </div>
```

...

```
handleInputChnage(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked: target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log("Current State is: " + JSON.stringify(this.state));
    alert("Current State is: " + JSON.stringify(this.state));
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

However, when I click the form entries such as first name and start typing, I cannot see it display any text. I take a look at the browser developer console. It shows a few warning and errors pasted below. One warning says I does not have an onChange method. Line 84 is the formGroup with firstname, line 121 is the formGroup with checkbox. I am not sure if this is the reason causing the issue. Any advice?

short version:

```
index.js:2178 Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
    in input (created by Input)
    in Input (at ContactComponent.js:84)

index.js:2178 Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
    in input (created by Input)
    in Input (at ContactComponent.js:121)
```

long verion:

```
index.js:2178 Warning: Please use `require("history").createBrowserHistory` instead of `require("history/createBrowserHistory")`. Support for the latter will be removed in the next major release.
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__ @ index.js:2178
printWarning @ warnAboutDeprecatedCJSRequire.js:17
./node_modules/history/warnAboutDeprecatedCJSRequire.js.module.exports @ warnAboutDeprecatedCJSRequire.js:30
./node_modules/history/createBrowserHistory.js @ createBrowserHistory.js:2
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:678
fn @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:88
./node_modules/react-router-dom/es/BrowserRouter.js @ BrowserRouter.js:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:678
fn @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:88
./node_modules/react-router-dom/es/index.js @ index.js:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:678
fn @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:88
./src/components/MenuComponent.js @ MainComponent.js:65
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:678
fn @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:88
./src/components/MainComponent.js @ HomeComponent.js:38
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:678
fn @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:88
./src/App.js @ App.css?9a66:26
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:678
fn @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:88
./src/index.js @ index.css?f255:26
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:678
fn @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:88
0 @ promotions.js:2
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:678
(anonymous) @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:724
(anonymous) @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:724
index.js:2178 Warning: Please use `require("history").createHashHistory` instead of `require("history/createHashHistory")`. Support for the latter will be removed in the next major release.
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__ @ index.js:2178
printWarning @ warnAboutDeprecatedCJSRequire.js:17
./node_modules/history/warnAboutDeprecatedCJSRequire.js.module.exports @ warnAboutDeprecatedCJSRequire.js:30
./node_modules/history/createHashHistory.js @ createHashHistory.js:2
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:678
fn @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:88
./node_modules/react-router-dom/es/HashRouter.js @ HashRouter.js:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:678
fn @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:88
./node_modules/react-router-dom/es/index.js @ index.js:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:678
fn @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:88
./src/components/MenuComponent.js @ MainComponent.js:65
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:678
fn @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:88
./src/components/MainComponent.js @ HomeComponent.js:38
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:678
fn @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:88
./src/App.js @ App.css?9a66:26
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:678
fn @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:88
./src/index.js @ index.css?f255:26
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:678
fn @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:88
0 @ promotions.js:2
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:678
(anonymous) @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:724
(anonymous) @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:724
index.js:2178 Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
    in input (created by Input)
    in Input (at ContactComponent.js:84)
    in div (created by Col)
    in Col (at ContactComponent.js:83)
    in div (created by FormGroup)
    in FormGroup (at ContactComponent.js:81)
    in form (created by Form)
    in Form (at ContactComponent.js:80)
    in div (at ContactComponent.js:79)
    in div (at ContactComponent.js:75)
    in div (at ContactComponent.js:38)
    in Contact (created by Route)
    in Route (at MainComponent.js:56)
    in Switch (at MainComponent.js:51)
    in div (at MainComponent.js:49)
    in Main (at App.js:11)
    in div (at App.js:10)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:9)
    in App (at src/index.js:12)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:11)
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__ @ index.js:2178
printWarning @ checkPropTypes.js:20
checkPropTypes @ checkPropTypes.js:82
./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactControlledValuePropTypes.checkPropTypes @ react-dom.development.js:1679
initWrapperState @ react-dom.development.js:1832
setInitialProperties @ react-dom.development.js:5990
finalizeInitialChildren @ react-dom.development.js:7499
completeWork @ react-dom.development.js:18978
completeUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22189
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22165
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22130
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:21756
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21188
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:24373
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:24758
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:21903
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:24757
render @ react-dom.development.js:24840
./src/index.js @ index.js:10
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:678
fn @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:88
0 @ promotions.js:2
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:678
(anonymous) @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:724
(anonymous) @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:724
index.js:2178 Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
    in input (created by Input)
    in Input (at ContactComponent.js:121)
    in label (created by Label)
    in Label (at ContactComponent.js:120)
    in div (created by FormGroup)
    in FormGroup (at ContactComponent.js:119)
    in div (created by Col)
    in Col (at ContactComponent.js:118)
    in div (created by FormGroup)
    in FormGroup (at ContactComponent.js:117)
    in form (created by Form)
    in Form (at ContactComponent.js:80)
    in div (at ContactComponent.js:79)
    in div (at ContactComponent.js:75)
    in div (at ContactComponent.js:38)
    in Contact (created by Route)
    in Route (at MainComponent.js:56)
    in Switch (at MainComponent.js:51)
    in div (at MainComponent.js:49)
    in Main (at App.js:11)
    in div (at App.js:10)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:9)
    in App (at src/index.js:12)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:11)
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__ @ index.js:2178
printWarning @ checkPropTypes.js:20
checkPropTypes @ checkPropTypes.js:82
./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactControlledValuePropTypes.checkPropTypes @ react-dom.development.js:1679
initWrapperState @ react-dom.development.js:1832
setInitialProperties @ react-dom.development.js:5990
finalizeInitialChildren @ react-dom.development.js:7499
completeWork @ react-dom.development.js:18978
completeUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22189
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22165
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22130
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:21756
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21188
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:24373
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:24758
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:21903
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:24757
render @ react-dom.development.js:24840
./src/index.js @ index.js:10
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:678
fn @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:88
0 @ promotions.js:2
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:678
(anonymous) @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:724
(anonymous) @ bootstrap be8518f88e4da5f2e0b3:724
index.js:2178 Warning: Legacy context API has been detected within a strict-mode tree.

The old API will be supported in all 16.x releases, but applications using it should migrate to the new version.

Please update the following components: Link, Route, Router, Switch, Transition

    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:9)
    in App (at src/index.js:12)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:11)
```

Comment: Yes, that error what cause what you are seeing. If I had to guess, I'd say your `<Input>` component isn't passing down the `onChange` and `value` props properly. Can you show us the code for that component?

Comment: You have a typo in the handler name, is that it ? `handleInputChnage`

Comment: @JulienVerneaut good catch...although i realized i used that universally in this app.Let me fix that and see what happen.

Comment: Yes. It is fixed. Thank both of you! If you would like to create that as an answer. I am happy to take it.